# TableView Reload data is not calling cellForRowAtIndexPath

Tags: iphone, swift, xcode, uitableview

I am Using UITableView For Display some data. But I have Seperated the Datasource and Delegate Methods to another class. So my TableViewController is not having Any delegate Methods. They are in Seperate Class.

So when the tableview loads for the First Time, It loads the values. but when i use `tableView.reloadData` on a button click of a cell , It does not calls the  `cellForRawAtIndexPath` Method. But it calls `numberOfRawsInSection` and other methods.

Here is my Controller Class

```
class AdvancedSearch: UITableViewController , PopOverViewDelegate{

@IBOutlet var model: AdvancedSearchDataModel!
let dataModel = AdvancedSearchDataModel()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    tableView.registerNib(UINib(nibName: "AgeCell", bundle: nil), forCellReuseIdentifier: "AgeCell")
    tableView.registerNib(UINib(nibName: "ExperienceCell", bundle: nil), forCellReuseIdentifier: "ExperienceCell")
    tableView.registerNib(UINib(nibName: "CityCell", bundle: nil), forCellReuseIdentifier: "CityCell")
    tableView.registerNib(UINib(nibName: "StateCell", bundle: nil), forCellReuseIdentifier: "StateCell")
    tableView.registerNib(UINib(nibName: "DateTimeCell", bundle: nil), forCellReuseIdentifier: "DateTimeCell")
    tableView.registerNib(UINib(nibName: "GenderCell", bundle: nil), forCellReuseIdentifier: "GenderCell")
    tableView.registerNib(UINib(nibName: "ResultButtonCell", bundle: nil), forCellReuseIdentifier: "ResultButtonCell")

    //tableView.dataSource = model
    //tableView.delegate = model
    tableView.separatorColor = UIColor.grayColor()
    tableView.allowsSelection = false
    tableView.separatorStyle = UITableViewCellSeparatorStyle.None

}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

override func viewWillTransitionToSize(size: CGSize, withTransitionCoordinator coordinator: UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinator) {
    tableView.reloadData()
}




// MARK: - DropDown PopOver Delegates

func valueOfTheFieldWhenSelect(tableViewCell: UITableViewCell, value: String, indexPath: NSIndexPath) {

        let data = AdvancedSearchDataModel()
        data.buttonTitle = value
        self.tableView.delegate = data
        self.tableView.dataSource = data
        self.tableView.reloadData()

}
```

Here is my Datasource and Delegates in Seperate Class

```
class AdvancedSearchDataModel: NSObject , UITableViewDataSource , UITableViewDelegate , AdvanceSearchDropDownButtonDelegate , UIPopoverPresentationControllerDelegate {


let data = ["Age","Experience","City" , "State" , "Gender" , "Date and Time"]

// set this proprty in PopOverViewDelegate method
var buttonTitle : String?




// MARK: - TableView Datasource

func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return 1
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    print("Count : \(data.count)")
    return data.count + 1
}

   func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    switch indexPath.row {
    case 0:
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("AgeCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! AgeCell
        applyStyleForButton(cell.selectAge)
        let frame = CGRectMake(0, cell.frame.size.height - 2, cell.frame.size.width,2)
        let additionalSeparator = UIView(frame: frame)
        additionalSeparator.backgroundColor = UIColor.grayColor()
        cell.addSubview(additionalSeparator)

        if buttonTitle != nil {
            cell.selectAge.setTitle(buttonTitle, forState: .Normal)
        }

        cell.indexPath = indexPath
        cell.dropDownDelegate = self

        return cell
    case 1:
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("ExperienceCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! ExperienceCell
        applyStyleForButton(cell.selectExperinceBtn)
        let frame = CGRectMake(0, cell.frame.size.height - 2, cell.frame.size.width,2)

        let additionalSeparator = UIView(frame: frame)

        additionalSeparator.backgroundColor = UIColor.grayColor()
        cell.addSubview(additionalSeparator)
        return cell
    case 2:
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("CityCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! CityCell
        applyStyleForButton(cell.cityButton)
        let frame = CGRectMake(0, cell.frame.size.height - 2, cell.frame.size.width,2)

        let additionalSeparator = UIView(frame: frame)

        additionalSeparator.backgroundColor = UIColor.grayColor()
        cell.addSubview(additionalSeparator)
        return cell
    case 3:
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("StateCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! StateCell
        applyStyleForButton(cell.stateButton)
        let frame = CGRectMake(0, cell.frame.size.height - 2, cell.frame.size.width,2)

        let additionalSeparator = UIView(frame: frame)

        additionalSeparator.backgroundColor = UIColor.grayColor()
        cell.addSubview(additionalSeparator)
        return cell
    case 4:
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("GenderCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! GenderCell
        let frame = CGRectMake(0, cell.frame.size.height - 2, cell.frame.size.width,2)

        let additionalSeparator = UIView(frame: frame)

        additionalSeparator.backgroundColor = UIColor.grayColor()
        cell.addSubview(additionalSeparator)
        return cell
    case 5:
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("DateTimeCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! DateTimeCell
        applyStyleForButton(cell.datebutton)
        applyStyleForButton(cell.timeButton)
        let frame = CGRectMake(0, cell.frame.size.height - 2, cell.frame.size.width,2)

        let additionalSeparator = UIView(frame: frame)

        additionalSeparator.backgroundColor = UIColor.grayColor()
        cell.addSubview(additionalSeparator)
        return cell
    case 6:
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("ResultButtonCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! ResultButtonCell
        let frame = CGRectMake(0, cell.frame.size.height - 2, cell.frame.size.width,2)

        let additionalSeparator = UIView(frame: frame)

        additionalSeparator.backgroundColor = UIColor.grayColor()
        cell.addSubview(additionalSeparator)
        return cell
    default:
        return UITableViewCell()
    }




}



// MARK: - TableView Delegates

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGFloat {

    if indexPath.row == 5 {
        return 150
    }else{
        return 94
    }

}

// MARK: - Styling

func applyStyleForButton(button : UIButton){

    button.layer.borderColor = UIColor.grayColor().CGColor
    button.layer.borderWidth = 1
    button.layer.cornerRadius = 5
    button.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor()

}


// MARK: - DropDown Delegates


func openAgeDropDown(by button: UIButton, and cell: AgeCell,indexPath : NSIndexPath)
{
    print("Age opened")
    let tableViewController = DropDownController(style: .Plain, menuItems: ["10","20","30"],cell: cell , index: indexPath)
    tableViewController.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationStyle.Popover
    tableViewController.preferredContentSize = CGSizeMake(button.frame.width, button.frame.width)

    // assigning the delegate in tableView to fill the textfield
    tableViewController.delegate = AdvancedSearch()

    let popoverPresentationController = tableViewController.popoverPresentationController
    popoverPresentationController?.permittedArrowDirections = .Any
    popoverPresentationController?.delegate = self
    popoverPresentationController?.sourceView = button
    popoverPresentationController?.sourceRect = button.bounds

    UIApplication.sharedApplication().keyWindow?.rootViewController!.presentViewController(tableViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)

}


// MARK: - PopOver Delegates

  func adaptivePresentationStyleForPresentationController(controller: UIPresentationController) -> UIModalPresentationStyle {
    return UIModalPresentationStyle.None
}}
```

Please Guide me

Comment: What's the reason to use multiple nibs rather than conveniently design all cells directly in the target table view?

Comment: I have Plenty of custom cells. so no space available in the TableViewController Itself. thats why i load them via nibs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The methods is not calling because everytime you are creating a new object of `AdvancedSearchDataModel`. instead this assign delegate in viewDidLoad. don't need to create new object of `AdvancedSearchDataModel`

in `viewDidLoad`

```
...
tableView.separatorColor = UIColor.grayColor()
tableView.allowsSelection = false
tableView.separatorStyle = UITableViewCellSeparatorStyle.None
tableView.delegate = self.model
 tableView.dataSource = self.model
```

and in `valueOfTheFieldWhenSelect`

```
func valueOfTheFieldWhenSelect(tableViewCell: UITableViewCell, value: String, indexPath: NSIndexPath) {

    self.model.buttonTitle = value
    self.tableView.reloadData()
 }
```

Comment: I will try and let you know @sahil . thanx a lot

Comment: It cosues me a error. telling that self.model is nil

Comment: because the property is not connected. connect it from storyboard.

Comment: I is connected @Sahil. it loads the cells at first time. but when i need to reload again it throws the error

Comment: i don't think it is connected. check it  in viewDidLoad  print(self.model).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/126901/discussion-between-darshana-and-sahil).

Comment: it is Connected